What's the best way to get the oil smell out of my house after frying food?
I love frying food (the latest obsession being corndogs). But my house reeks for days after cooking with copious amounts of oil. Even if I leave the windows open, it doesn't really help. Any suggestions for sprays or hacks to get the smell out of my house?
